# Rechart tooltip issue: shows background elements

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I have  3 bar charts one by one.
and i have to show custom tooltip but it shows background content when it height is higher than the bar chart.
this is the custom tooltip component

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }: any) => {
    return (
      <div className="custom-tooltip">
        <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload[0].value}`}</p>
        <p className="intro">{getIntroOfPage(label)}</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
      </div>
    );
};
```

see below [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-with-customized-content-forked-mtsi2) for demo.
Please guide how to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [github](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/302#issuecomment-265613912) issue you can add `zIndex` in your tooltip like below:-

```
<Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} wrapperStyle={{ zIndex: 1000 }}/>
```